# How do I connect my tablet to my tv?

Tags: hardware, external-display

I broke my Coby Kyros' screen and now I want to make an emulator console out of it. 
The problem is my model did not have an HDMI out.

I noticed that there is a ribbon cable connecting the tablet screen to the rest of the tablet.
So I need a way to connect my tablet's ribbon cable to a television.

Is there any way to convert that ribbon cable slot to a VGA/HDMI/RCA port?
Or is there some sort of ribbon cable to VGA/HDMI/RCA cable?

Answer (score 1):

I think its possible, but you'll need to read the datasheets and the pinouts for the ribbon cable and the VGA that is if you want to make it yourself.. Otherwise, I think you can purchase a ready made one from the shops e.g. eBay.

Here are a couple of links that might help:
http://forums.bit-tech.net/showthread.php?p=1888439

http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_kw=vga+ribbon+cable

Then you can purchase a VGA to HDMI convertor cable.